# How to correctly point to a struct member in C?

Tags: c, csv, struct, complex-numbers

I have created a very simple "csvread" function in C, which will read from CSV files as implied. (In this case, for testing, I have edited it slightly so that I can write dummy data to a file and then read it). I have created a struct to store complex data. However, my psuedo-csv file only contains the real part of the data I need to use. I would like to store this data into a "data.real" array. However, I can't seem to get the correct syntax down. (Although, admittedly this is probably more of an issue of understanding pointers completely rather than just syntax). Any help would be appreciated!

In the below code, I know that the following function call is the problem:

```
 csvread("test.txt", &data->real);
```

However, I have tried multiple variations of the second argument, and this is the only one I can come up with that compiles.

I have gotten my code to work when data is not a structure. For example, if data was declared:

```
double data[10];
```

So, as you can (hopefully) see I am having trouble with understanding pointers to structure members.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 10

typedef struct Complex
{
   double real;
   double imag;
}complex;

void csvread(char *filename, double *data_out);

int main(void)
{
   complex *data;
   csvread("test.txt", &data->real);
   for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
   {
       printf("%f\n", data[i].real);
   }
}  

// This function reads csv files
void csvread(char *filename, double *data_out)
{
    FILE *file;
    char *no_commas; // character buffer to store strings without comma parse
    double *buffer; // character data converted to double type
    const char comma[2] = ",";
    char *csv;
    char *token;
    int file_size;
    int i = 0;

    // Read CSV file
    file = fopen(filename,"w+"); // change to "r" if read only
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n The file requested cannot be found.");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(file, "%s", "1.18493,0.68594,-7.65962,9.84941,10.34054,7.86571,0.04500,11.49505,-8.49410,-0.54901"); 
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET); // return to beginning of the file

    // Find the file size in bytes 
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); // go to end of file
    file_size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET); //  return to beginning of file

    // Allocate buffer memory
    no_commas = malloc((file_size) * sizeof(char));
    buffer = malloc((file_size) * sizeof(double));

    if (no_commas == NULL || buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory when reading %s.\n\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((csv = fgets(no_commas, (file_size + 1), file)) != NULL) // fgets is used as file has no newline characters
    {
        // Remove Commas from string
        token = strtok(csv, comma);
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            //printf("%s\n", token); 
            buffer[i] = atof(strdup(token));
            token = strtok(NULL, comma);
            //printf("%f\n", buffer[i]); 
            i++;
        }
    }
    data_out = buffer;
    fclose(file);
    free(no_commas);
    free(buffer);
}
```

Output:

```
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

Expected Output:

```
 1.18493
 0.68594
-7.65962
 9.84941
10.34054
 7.86571
 0.04500
11.49505
-8.49410
-0.54901
```

**EDIT**: Thank you all for your comments and help! I have marked Johnny Mopp's answer as most helpful. This question evolved into more about allocating memory than intended, which ended up being very informative and helpful.

Comment: Your problem is that `data` is not initialized, and therefore pointing nowhere valid.

Comment: You are not asking the right question. In order to point something, this something has to exist. While your `data` is not allocated at all.

Comment: Does the csv file only contain the real part?

Comment: Anyhow, the prototype should be either `void csvread(char *filename, complex *data_out);` in the case you allocate the array before `csvread` call, or `void csvread(char *filename, complex **data_out);` in the case you allocate the data in the `csvread`.

Comment: @DaBler yes, the csv file contains only the real part. I will try updating my code as you have stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't allocate just the `real` part. You need to alloc the entire struct - even if you just use the `real` part. If you were using an array, it would be like:

```
complex data[10];
data[0].real = 1.0;
data[1].real = 2.0;
// etc..
```

But you will have to dynamically allocate the `complex` array since the number of items in the file is not known ahead of time (I assume). You can allocate 1 `complex` object at a time, resizing the array as you go.

```
// Prototype has changed to pointer-to-pointer complex
// Return value is the number of items read
int csvread(char *filename, complex **data);

int main(void)
{
   complex *data = NULL;
   int num_records = csvread("test.txt", &data);
   for(int i = 0; i < num_records; i++)
   {
       printf("%f\n", data[i].real);
   }
   free(data);
}  

// This function reads csv files
int csvread(char *filename, complex **data_out)
{
    // This will be used to avoid always having to dereference
    // the data_out parameter
    complex *array = NULL;
    int num_records = 0;

    while (1) {
        double value = // read a value from the file.....
        // If error or end of file break out of loop

        // Allocate space for another complex object
        array = realloc(array, sizeof(complex) * (num_records + 1));
        if (NULL == array) // handle error

        // Store just the real part
        array[num_records].real = value;
        // Also, you can initialize imag here but not required
        array[num_records].imag = 0;
        num_records += 1;
    }

    // Store and return
    *data_out = array;
    return num_records;
}
```

---

Based on updated comments: Off the top of my head, here's one way to handle multiple files. First, create 2 functions: one to read the entire contents of a file, and one to replace `strtok`. The reason we need the second one is because of the way `strtok` works, you can only use it on one string at a time and we want to use it on two. Then, change the `readcsv` function to take 2 file names. This is untested and may have errors.

```
// Create a function that just opens and reads a file
char *load_file(const char *path) {
    // TODO:
    // Open the file and read entire contents
    // return string with contents

    // If path is NULL, must return NULL

    // Must return NULL if file does not exist
    // or read error
}

// Use this function instead of strok so you 
// can use on 2 string simultaneously
double get_next_value(char **string)
{
    char *start = *string;
    char *end   = *string;

    // Loop until comma or end of string
    while (*end && *end != ',') end++;
    // If comma, terminate and increment
    if (*end) *end++ = 0;
    // Update for next time
    *string = end;
    return atof(start);
}

// This function reads csv files
int csvread(char *real_filename, char *imag_filename, complex **data_out)
{
    // This will be used to avoid always having to dereference
    // the data_out parameter
    complex *array = NULL;
    int num_records = 0;

    // Load each file into a string. May be NULL
    char *real_data_orig = load_file(real_filename);
    char *imag_data_orig = load_file(imag_filename);

    // Temporary copies of the pointers. Keep the originals
    // to free() later. These will be modified
    char *real_data = real_data_orig;
    char *imag_data = imag_data_orig;

    while (1) {
        // Check for data. Make sure pointer is not
        // NULL and it is still pointing to something
        // that is not '\0'
        bool has_real = real_data && *real_data;
        bool has_imag = imag_data && *imag_data;

        // No data? Done.
        if (!has_real && !has_imag) break;

        // Allocate space for another complex object
        array = realloc(array, sizeof(complex) * (num_records + 1));
        if (NULL == array) // handle error

        // Store the real part (if there is one)
        if (has_real) {
            array[num_records].real = get_next_value(&real_data);
        }
        // Store the imag part (if there is one)
        if (has_imag) {
            array[num_records].imag = get_next_value(&imag_data);
        }
        num_records += 1;
    }

    // Free the file contents
    free(real_data_orig);
    free(imag_data_orig);

    // Store and return
    *data_out = array;
    return num_records;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense to me, but I will also need to store the imaginary data as well. I suppose that if I was to rewrite my csvread, I could add a parameter that could deal with this. I will update my post to show how I am reading. It is very basic.

Comment: @user15 I'm not sure what you mean by _store the imaginary data as well_. Do mean in the csv file?

Comment: there are multiple csv files. One file contains the real data set, while the other contains the imaginary data set. I will need to read both eventually. With my csvread function, I had intended to call it twice so that I would have both data sets in one struct.

Comment: @user15 You can do that. When you call it the 2nd time, don't `realloc` anything. Just store the data in `imag`. Or modify to parse both files at the same time.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help! Do you think that modification of reading two files can be done with what I currently have or would you recommend a total rewrite of my function (disregarding the writing to file portion)? I also have a special case where I have a dataset with only real values. Would you recommend writing a seperate function for that or do you think it would be a simple addition?

Comment: @user15 I've updated my answer. This is one way to do it - may or may not be the best. Hopefully it will give you some good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In java this would be seen as a *NullPointerException*, you don't get this kinds of errors in C, but that comes with a responsibility as well. Deferencing a null pointer in C (as you did) may respond in many ways. As the comments had said you need to allocate  the `data` pointer.

```
complex *data = malloc(sizeof(complex));
```

And you should free the memory allocated with `malloc` as well, so in the end of the code just before returning the status of your program to the OS (which you didn't) you should do:

```
free(data);
```

I'm not sure of how your csvread works but it might not work using nothing less than an array of complex structures. The code below allocates 10 complex numbers initializing them all, inside the `csvread` function you might have to do some modifications to iterate over them as you showed that with simple array declarations your code works.

```
complex *data = calloc(10, sizeof(complex));
```

The code above allocates 10 *complex structures* and the pointer points to the first one allocated. To iterate over them you could index them with numbers (e.g `data[0].real = 4`) or use pointer arithmetic. I have a strong feeling that you will have to modify the way you iterate over the `data_out` pointer inside the `csvread` function.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Noted. I have edited my code as ranu has stated, but I am still getting an output of 0.00000.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I will show you my csv read code, as I stated under Johnny's answer.